# How to extract xy data from Prophet.plot_components()

Tags: plot, facebook-prophet

I have data on disease case counts per unit time so that I may predict outbreaks. I used Facebook Prophet's plot_components function to extract the base trend from the data which Prophet allows one to do quite easily:

```
model = Prophet()
model.fit(df)

future = model.make_future_dataframe(periods=0)
forecast = model.predict(future)

model.plot_components(forecast)
```

Which expectedly yielded me [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Whrj8.png) plot.

I need those xy values though for my analysis which I can't figure out. The docs for Prophet weren't helpful nor was diving into the source code on github. There also doesn't seem to be a callable method or attribute on the figure object which returns the values.

Any thoughts would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

You have it in the forecast dataframe (check the "weekly" column)